# Error when installing Pillow on Fedora

Tags: python, fedora, python-imaging-library

I am trying to setup the pyautogui package, which requires pillow. I have got all the dependencies according to the documentation, but am still having an error. I am relatively inexperienced with Linux, so there is a good chance this is a problem with incompatible versions or something obvious.

Here is some of my log:

```html
[cole@colelinux ~]$ pip3 install pillow
Downloading/unpacking pillow
  Downloading Pillow-4.3.0.tar.gz (13.9MB): 13.9MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package pillow
    
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking olefile (from pillow)
  Downloading olefile-0.44.zip (74kB): 74kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/olefile/setup.py) egg_info for package olefile
    
Installing collected packages: pillow, olefile
  Running setup.py install for pillow
    
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    building 'PIL._imaging' extension


...



warning: no files found matching '*.sh'

no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'

warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution

writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running build_ext

building 'PIL._imaging' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_imaging.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c outline.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/outline.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/Bands.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Bands.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/Convert.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Convert.o

_imaging.c:74:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/Bands.c:19:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/Convert.c:36:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

outline.c:20:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/Dib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Dib.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/Fill.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Fill.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/GifDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/GifDecode.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/JpegEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/JpegEncode.o

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/Fill.c:19:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/Dib.c:23:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/GifDecode.c:25:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/JpegEncode.c:23:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/Offset.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Offset.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/Quant.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Quant.o

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/Offset.c:18:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/PcxDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/PcxDecode.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/RawEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/RawEncode.o

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/Quant.c:21:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/PcxDecode.c:17:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/Unpack.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Unpack.o

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/RawEncode.c:21:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/ZipDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/ZipDecode.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="4.3.0" -I/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c libImaging/BoxBlur.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/BoxBlur.o

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/Unpack.c:33:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

libImaging/BoxBlur.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

In file included from libImaging/Imaging.h:14:0,

                 from libImaging/ZipDecode.c:19:

libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

Building using 4 processes

gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_imaging.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/decode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/encode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/map.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/display.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/outline.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/path.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Access.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Resample.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Bands.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/BcnDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/BitDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Blend.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Chops.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Convert.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Copy.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Crc32.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Crop.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Dib.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Draw.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Effects.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/EpsEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/File.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Fill.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Filter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/FliDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Geometry.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/GetBBox.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/GifDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/GifEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/HexDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Histo.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/JpegDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/JpegEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/LzwDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Matrix.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/ModeFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Negative.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Offset.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Pack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/PackDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Palette.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Paste.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Quant.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/QuantOctree.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/QuantHash.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/QuantHeap.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/PcdDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/PcxDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/PcxEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Point.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/RankFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/RawDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/RawEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Storage.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/SgiRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Unpack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/XbmDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/XbmEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/ZipDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/ZipEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/TiffDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/BoxBlur.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/QuantPngQuant.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/codec_fd.o -L/usr/include/libpng16 -L/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib64 -ljpeg -lz -ltiff -lpython3.4m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL/_imaging.cpython-34m.so

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_imaging.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/decode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/encode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/map.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/display.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/outline.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/path.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Access.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Resample.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Bands.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/BcnDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/BitDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Blend.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Chops.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Convert.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Copy.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Crc32.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Crop.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Dib.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Draw.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Effects.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/EpsEncode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/File.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Fill.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Filter.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/FliDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Geometry.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/GetBBox.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/GifDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/GifEncode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/HexDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Histo.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/JpegDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/JpegEncode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/LzwDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Matrix.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/ModeFilter.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Negative.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Offset.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Pack.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/PackDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Palette.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Paste.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Quant.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/QuantOctree.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/QuantHash.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/QuantHeap.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/PcdDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/PcxDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/PcxEncode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Point.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/RankFilter.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/RawDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/RawEncode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Storage.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/SgiRleDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Unpack.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/XbmDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/XbmEncode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/ZipDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/ZipEncode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/TiffDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/BoxBlur.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/QuantPngQuant.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging/codec_fd.o: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-a68sxz9n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-bvbdm6ii/pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /home/cole/.pip/pip.log
[cole@colelinux ~]$
```

I am using fedora V21
Ask me if you need any other info.

Comment: Hint: `dnf list installed | grep python3-devel`

Comment: It looks like you're missing `python-dev`. Install the headers by doing `yum install python-devel`

Comment: I ran "sudo yum install python-devel" but it says that it is already installed and latest version

Comment: Fixed it! I had to install 'python3-devel' instead of 'python-devel' Post can now be locked.